Tkinter Scrollbar issue
Pleaase someone fix the scrollbaar for me and also add scrollbars for the third canvas.
Actually i have created data structure visualizer. and facing a scrollbar,cureently ia cant scoll to the third canvas.
Language- pyhton
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

class VisualizerApp:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Data Structure and Sorting Algorithm")
        self.root.geometry("1200x800")

        # Canvas for the Main Window
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
        self.canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # Scrollbars for the main window
        self.scroll_x = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=self.canvas.xview)
        self.scroll_x.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)
        self.scroll_y = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.scroll_y.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

        # Frame for the widgets
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.frame, anchor='nw')

        # Configure Canvas scrolling
        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.on_frame_configure)
        self.canvas.config(xscrollcommand=self.scroll_x.set, yscrollcommand=self.scroll_y.set)

        # Setup UI
        self.setup_ui()

    def setup_ui(self):
        # Frame for data structure selection and visualization
        self.data_frame = tk.Frame(self.frame)
        self.data_frame.pack(padx=10, pady=10, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # Dropdown menus for data structures
        tk.Label(self.data_frame, text="Select Data Structure:", fg="black").pack(padx=10, pady=5, anchor=tk.W)
        options = ["Array", "Stack", "Linked List", "Set", "Tuple", "Dictionary"]
        self.data_structure = tk.StringVar(value=options[0])
        data_structure_menu = tk.OptionMenu(self.data_frame, self.data_structure, *options)
        data_structure_menu.pack(padx=10, pady=5, anchor=tk.W)

        # Entry for the values
        tk.Label(self.data_frame, text="Enter Values (Comma Separated):", fg="black").pack(padx=10, pady=5, anchor=tk.W)
        self.data_entry = tk.Entry(self.data_frame)
        self.data_entry.pack(padx=10, pady=5, anchor=tk.W)

        # Canvas for visualizing data structures
        self.canvas_data_structure = tk.Canvas(self.data_frame, bg="white", width=1000, height=300)
        self.canvas_data_structure.pack(padx=10, pady=5, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # Scrollbars for data structure canvas
        self.scroll_x_data = tk.Scrollbar(self.data_frame, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=self.canvas_data_structure.xview)
        self.scroll_x_data.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)
        self.canvas_data_structure.config(xscrollcommand=self.scroll_x_data.set)

        self.scroll_y_data = tk.Scrollbar(self.data_frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=self.canvas_data_structure.yview)
        self.scroll_y_data.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
        self.canvas_data_structure.config(yscrollcommand=self.scroll_y_data.set)

        # Button for visualizing data structure
        self.visualize_button = tk.Button(self.data_frame, text="Visualize Data Structure", command=self.visualize_data_structure)
        self.visualize_button.pack(padx=10, pady=5)

        # Frame for sorting algorithm selection and visualization
        self.sort_frame = tk.Frame(self.frame)
        self.sort_frame.pack(padx=10, pady=10, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # Dropdown menu for sorting algorithms
        tk.Label(self.sort_frame, text="Select Sorting Algorithm:", fg="black").pack(padx=10, pady=5, anchor=tk.W)
        options2 = ["Bubble Sort", "Insertion Sort", "Quick Sort"]
        self.sorting_algos = tk.StringVar(value=options2[0])
        sorting_algorithm_menu = tk.OptionMenu(self.sort_frame, self.sorting_algos, *options2)
        sorting_algorithm_menu.pack(padx=10, pady=5, anchor=tk.W)

        # Button for sort and visualize
        self.sort_button = tk.Button(self.sort_frame, text="Sort and Visualize", command=self.sort_and_visualize)
        self.sort_button.pack(padx=10, pady=5)

        # Frame and canvas for sorting visualization
        self.sorting_canvas_frame = tk.Frame(self.sort_frame)
        self.sorting_canvas_frame.pack(padx=10, pady=5, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        self.canvas_sorting = tk.Canvas(self.sorting_canvas_frame, bg="white", width=1000, height=300)
        self.canvas_sorting.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # Scrollbars for sorting canvas
        self.scroll_x_sort = tk.Scrollbar(self.sorting_canvas_frame, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=self.canvas_sorting.xview)
        self.scroll_x_sort.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)
        self.canvas_sorting.config(xscrollcommand=self.scroll_x_sort.set)

        self.scroll_y_sort = tk.Scrollbar(self.sorting_canvas_frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=self.canvas_sorting.yview)
        self.scroll_y_sort.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
        self.canvas_sorting.config(yscrollcommand=self.scroll_y_sort.set)

        # Text area for the explanation
        self.explanation_frame = tk.Frame(self.frame)
        self.explanation_frame.pack(padx=10, pady=10, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        self.explanation_text = tk.Text(self.explanation_frame, height=10, width=100)
        self.explanation_text.pack(padx=10, pady=5, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    def on_frame_configure(self, event):
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))
        self.canvas_data_structure.config(scrollregion=self.canvas_data_structure.bbox("all"))
        self.canvas_sorting.config(scrollregion=self.canvas_sorting.bbox("all"))

    def visualize_data_structure(self):
        data_type = self.data_structure.get()
        values = self.data_entry.get()

        if not data_type or not values:
            messagebox.showerror("Input Error", "Please select a data structure and enter values")
            return
        
        try:
            self.data = list(map(int, values.split(',')))
        except ValueError:
            messagebox.showerror("Input Error", "Please enter valid integer values.")
            return
        
        if data_type == "Array" or data_type == "Tuple":
            self.draw_array(self.data, self.canvas_data_structure)
        elif data_type == "Stack":
            self.draw_stack(self.data, self.canvas_data_structure)
        elif data_type == "Linked List":
            self.draw_linked_list(self.data, self.canvas_data_structure)
        elif data_type == "Set":
            self.draw_set(set(self.data), self.canvas_data_structure)
        elif data_type == "Dictionary":
            self.draw_dictionary({i: val for i, val in enumerate(self.data)}, self.canvas_data_structure)

    def draw_array(self, data, canvas, color_array=None):
        canvas.delete("all")
        canvas_height = 180
        canvas_width = max(800, len(data) * 100)
        bar_width = canvas_width / (len(data) + 1)
        bar_height = 40
        bar_width = 60
        offset = 30
        spacing = 10

        if color_array is None:
            color_array = ["red" for _ in data]

        for i, height in enumerate(data):
            x0 = i * (bar_width + spacing)+offset
            y0 = canvas_height//2 - bar_height//2
            x1 = x0 + bar_width
            y1 = y0 + bar_height
            
            color = color_array[i]
            canvas.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill=color)
            canvas.create_text((x0 + x1) // 2, (y0 + y1) // 2, text=str(height), fill="white")

        canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
        self.root.update_idletasks()

    def draw_stack(self, data, canvas):
        canvas.delete("all")
        canvas_height = 180
        canvas_width = 80
        bar_width = 60
        offset = 30
        spacing = 10
        
        for i, height in enumerate(data):
            x0 = offset
            y0 = canvas_height - (i + 1) * (bar_width + spacing)
            x1 = offset + bar_width
            y1 = canvas_height - i * (bar_width + spacing)
            
            canvas.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill="blue")
            canvas.create_text((x0 + x1) // 2, (y0 + y1) // 2, text=str(height), fill="white")
        
        canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
        self.root.update_idletasks()

    def draw_linked_list(self, data, canvas):
        canvas.delete("all")
        canvas_height = 180
        canvas_width = max(800, len(data) * 100)
        bar_width = canvas_width / (len(data) + 1)
        node_width=60
        node_height = 40
        offset = 30
        spacing = 40

        for i, value in enumerate(data):
            x0 = i * (node_width + spacing) + offset
            y0 = canvas_height // 2 - node_height // 2
            x1 = x0 + node_width
            y1 = y0 + node_height
            
            canvas.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill="green")
            canvas.create_text((x0 + x1) // 2, (y0 + y1) // 2, text=str(value), fill="white")
            if i < len(data) - 1:
                x2 = x1 + spacing // 2
                y2 = canvas_height // 2
                x3 = x1 + spacing
                canvas.create_line(x1, y2, x2, y2, arrow=tk.LAST, fill="black")

        canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
        self.root.update_idletasks()

    def draw_set(self, data, canvas):
        canvas.delete("all")
        canvas_height = 180
        canvas_width = max(800, len(data) * 100)
        bar_width = canvas_width / (len(data) + 1)
        bar_height = 40
        bar_width = 60
        offset = 30
        spacing = 10

        for i, value in enumerate(data):
            x0 = i * (bar_width + spacing)+offset
            y0 = canvas_height//2 - bar_height//2
            x1 = x0 + bar_width
            y1 = y0 + bar_height
            
            canvas.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill="purple")
            canvas.create_text((x0 + x1) // 2, (y0 + y1) // 2, text=str(value), fill="white")

        canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
        self.root.update_idletasks()

    def draw_dictionary(self, data, canvas):
        canvas.delete("all")
        canvas_height = 180
        canvas_width = max(800, len(data) * 100)
        bar_width = canvas_width / (len(data) + 1)
        bar_height = 40
        bar_width = 60
        offset = 30
        spacing = 10

        for i, (key, value) in enumerate(data.items()):
            x0 = i * (bar_width + spacing)+offset
            y0 = canvas_height//2 - bar_height//2
            x1 = x0 + bar_width
            y1 = y0 + bar_height
            
            canvas.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill="orange")
            canvas.create_text((x0 + x1) // 2, (y0 + y1) // 2 - 10, text=str(key), fill="white")
            canvas.create_text((x0 + x1) // 2, (y0 + y1) // 2 + 10, text=str(value), fill="white")

        canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
        self.root.update_idletasks()

    def sort_and_visualize(self):
        sorting_algo = self.sorting_algos.get()
        values = self.data_entry.get()

        if not sorting_algo or not values:
            messagebox.showerror("Input Error", "Please select a sorting algorithm and enter values")
            return
        
        try:
            self.data = list(map(int, values.split(',')))
        except ValueError:
            messagebox.showerror("Input Error", "Please enter valid integer values.")
            return

        if sorting_algo == "Bubble Sort":
            self.bubble_sort(self.data)
        elif sorting_algo == "Insertion Sort":
            self.insertion_sort(self.data)
        elif sorting_algo == "Quick Sort":
            self.quick_sort(self.data, 0, len(self.data) - 1)

    def bubble_sort(self, data):
        self.explanation_text.delete("1.0", tk.END)
        self.explanation_text.insert(tk.END, "Bubble Sort Explanation:\n\n")
        
        n = len(data)
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(0, n - i - 1):
                if data[j] > data[j + 1]:
                    data[j], data[j + 1] = data[j + 1], data[j]
                    self.draw_array(data, self.canvas_sorting, ["green" if x == data[j] else "red" if x == data[j+1] else "gray" for x in data])
                    self.explanation_text.insert(tk.END, f"Swapped {data[j+1]} and {data[j]}\n")
                    self.root.update()
                    time.sleep(1)
                    
        self.draw_array(data, self.canvas_sorting, ["green" for _ in data])

    def insertion_sort(self, data):
        self.explanation_text.delete("1.0", tk.END)
        self.explanation_text.insert(tk.END, "Insertion Sort Explanation:\n\n")
        
        for i in range(1, len(data)):
            key = data[i]
            j = i - 1
            while j >= 0 and key < data[j]:
                data[j + 1] = data[j]
                j -= 1
                self.draw_array(data, self.canvas_sorting, ["green" if x == key else "red" if x == data[j+1] else "gray" for x in data])
                self.explanation_text.insert(tk.END, f"Moved {data[j+1]} to position {j+2}\n")
                self.root.update()
                time.sleep(1)
            data[j + 1] = key
            self.draw_array(data, self.canvas_sorting, ["green" if x == key else "gray" for x in data])
            self.explanation_text.insert(tk.END, f"Inserted {key} at position {j+1}\n")

        self.draw_array(data, self.canvas_sorting, ["green" for _ in data])

    def quick_sort(self, data, low, high):
        if low < high:
            pi = self.partition(data, low, high)
            self.quick_sort(data, low, pi - 1)
            self.quick_sort(data, pi + 1, high)

    def partition(self, data, low, high):
        self.explanation_text.delete("1.0", tk.END)
        self.explanation_text.insert(tk.END, "Quick Sort Explanation:\n\n")
        
        i = low - 1
        pivot = data[high]

        for j in range(low, high):
            if data[j] < pivot:
                i += 1
                data[i], data[j] = data[j], data[i]
                self.draw_array(data, self.canvas_sorting, ["green" if x == pivot else "red" if x == data[i] else "gray" for x in data])
                self.explanation_text.insert(tk.END, f"Swapped {data[i]} with {data[j]}\n")
                self.root.update()
                time.sleep(1)

        data[i + 1], data[high] = data[high], data[i + 1]
        self.draw_array(data, self.canvas_sorting, ["green" if x == pivot else "red" if x == data[i+1] else "gray" for x in data])
        self.explanation_text.insert(tk.END, f"Moved pivot {pivot} to correct position\n")

        return i + 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = VisualizerApp(root)
    root.mainloop()


I am expecting a scrollbar for the main window that scroll through all the canvas and also a scroll bar for the third canvas.

Move all three root packs to the end before function.
    self.scroll_y.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
    self.scroll_x.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)
    self.canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

def on_frame_configure(self, event):

You cannot scroll both vertically and horizontally. Unless you add widgets inside Canvas.
Change this for both vertical and horizontal:
tk.Scrollbar(self.data_frame,

to:
tk.Scrollbar(self.canvas_data_structure,

Also this too:
tk.Scrollbar(self.sorting_canvas_frame,

to:
tk.Scrollbar(self.canvas_sorting 

Screenshot only when resizing:


The scroll bars of the third canvas representing the canvas_sorting should be configured for proper scrolling between all the canvases. More specifically, we need to do the following:
Configure the scroll bars for the third canvas called canvas_sorting.
Ensure all scrollbars are correctly bound to their respective canvases.
Changes will be in the code below to implement these.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

class VisualizerApp:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Data Structure and Sorting Algorithm")
        self.root.geometry("1200x800")

        # Canvas for the Main Window
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
        self.canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # Scrollbars for the main window
        self.scroll_x = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=self.canvas.xview)
        self.scroll_x.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)
        self.scroll_y = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.scroll_y.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

        # Frame for the widgets
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.frame, anchor='nw')

        # Configure Canvas scrolling
        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.on_frame_configure)
        self.canvas.config(xscrollcommand=self.scroll_x.set, yscrollcommand=self.scroll_y.set)

        # Setup UI
        self.setup_ui()

    def setup_ui(self):
        # Frame for data structure selection and visualization
        self.data_frame = tk.Frame(self.frame)
        self.data_frame.pack(padx=10, pady=10, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # Dropdown menus for data structures
        tk.Label(self.data_frame, text="Select Data Structure:", fg="black").pack(padx=10, pady=5, anchor=tk.W)
        options = ["Array", "Stack", "Linked List", "Set", "Tuple", "Dictionary"]
        self.data_structure = tk.StringVar(value=options[0])
        data_structure_menu = tk.OptionMenu(self.data_frame, self.data_structure, *options)
        data_structure_menu.pack(padx=10, pady=5, anchor=tk.W)

        # Entry for the values
        tk.Label(self.data_frame, text="Enter Values (Comma Separated):", fg="black").pack(padx=10, pady=5, anchor=tk.W)
        self.data_entry = tk.Entry(self.data_frame)
        self.data_entry.pack(padx=10, pady=5, anchor=tk.W)

        # Canvas for visualizing data structures
        self.canvas_data_structure = tk.Canvas(self.data_frame, bg="white", width=1000, height=300)
        self.canvas_data_structure.pack(padx=10, pady=5, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # Scrollbars for data structure canvas
        self.scroll_x_data = tk.Scrollbar(self.data_frame, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=self.canvas_data_structure.xview)
        self.scroll_x_data.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)
        self.canvas_data_structure.config(xscrollcommand=self.scroll_x_data.set)

        self.scroll_y_data = tk.Scrollbar(self.data_frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=self.canvas_data_structure.yview)
        self.scroll_y_data.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
        self.canvas_data_structure.config(yscrollcommand=self.scroll_y_data.set)

        # Button for visualizing data structure
        self.visualize_button = tk.Button(self.data_frame, text="Visualize Data Structure", command=self.visualize_data_structure)
        self.visualize_button.pack(padx=10, pady=5)

        # Frame for sorting algorithm selection and visualization
        self.sort_frame = tk.Frame(self.frame)
        self.sort_frame.pack(padx=10, pady=10, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # Dropdown menu for sorting algorithms
        tk.Label(self.sort_frame, text="Select Sorting Algorithm:", fg="black").pack(padx=10, pady=5, anchor=tk.W)
        options2 = ["Bubble Sort", "Insertion Sort", "Quick Sort"]
        self.sorting_algos = tk.StringVar(value=options2[0])
        sorting_algorithm_menu = tk.OptionMenu(self.sort_frame, self.sorting_algos, *options2)
        sorting_algorithm_menu.pack(padx=10, pady=5, anchor=tk.W)

        # Button for sort and visualize
        self.sort_button = tk.Button(self.sort_frame, text="Sort and Visualize", command=self.sort_and_visualize)
        self.sort_button.pack(padx=10, pady=5)

        # Frame and canvas for sorting visualization
        self.sorting_canvas_frame = tk.Frame(self.sort_frame)
        self.sorting_canvas_frame.pack(padx=10, pady=5, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        self.canvas_sorting = tk.Canvas(self.sorting_canvas_frame, bg="white", width=1000, height=300)
        self.canvas_sorting.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # Scrollbars for sorting canvas
        self.scroll_x_sort = tk.Scrollbar(self.sorting_canvas_frame, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=self.canvas_sorting.xview)
        self.scroll_x_sort.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)
        self.canvas_sorting.config(xscrollcommand=self.scroll_x_sort.set)

        self.scroll_y_sort = tk.Scrollbar(self.sorting_canvas_frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=self.canvas_sorting.yview)
        self.scroll_y_sort.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
        self.canvas_sorting.config(yscrollcommand=self.scroll_y_sort.set)

        # Text area for the explanation
        self.explanation_frame = tk.Frame(self.frame)
        self.explanation_frame.pack(padx=10, pady=10, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        self.explanation_text = tk.Text(self.explanation_frame, height=10, width=100)
        self.explanation_text.pack(padx=10, pady=5, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    def on_frame_configure(self, event):
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))
        self.canvas_data_structure.config(scrollregion=self.canvas_data_structure.bbox("all"))
        self.canvas_sorting.config(scrollregion=self.canvas_sorting.bbox("all"))

    def visualize_data_structure(self):
        data_type = self.data_structure.get()
        values = self.data_entry.get()

        if not data_type or not values:
            messagebox.showerror("Input Error", "Please select a data structure and enter values")
            return
        
        try:
            self.data = list(map(int, values.split(',')))
        except ValueError:
            messagebox.showerror("Input Error", "Please enter valid integer values.")
            return
        
        if data_type == "Array" or data_type == "Tuple":
            self.draw_array(self.data, self.canvas_data_structure)
        elif data_type == "Stack":
            self.draw_stack(self.data, self.canvas_data_structure)
        elif data_type == "Linked List":
            self.draw_linked_list(self.data, self.canvas_data_structure)
        elif data_type == "Set":
            self.draw_set(set(self.data), self.canvas_data_structure)
        elif data_type == "Dictionary":
            self.draw_dictionary({i: val for i, val in enumerate(self.data)}, self.canvas_data_structure)

    def draw_array(self, data, canvas, color_array=None):
        canvas.delete("all")
        canvas_height = 180
        canvas_width = max(800, len(data) * 100)
        bar_width = canvas_width / (len(data) + 1)
        bar_height = 40
        bar_width = 60
        offset = 30
        spacing = 10

        if color_array is None:
            color_array = ["red" for _ in data]

        for i, height in enumerate(data):
            x0 = i * (bar_width + spacing)+offset
            y0 = canvas_height//2 - bar_height//2
            x1 = x0 + bar_width
            y1 = y0 + bar_height
            
            color = color_array[i]
            canvas.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill=color)
            canvas.create_text((x0 + x1) // 2, (y0 + y1) // 2, text=str(height), fill="white")

        canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
        self.root.update_idletasks()

    def draw_stack(self, data, canvas):
        canvas.delete("all")
        canvas_height = 180
        canvas_width = 80
        bar_width = 60
        offset = 30
        spacing = 10
        
        for i, height in enumerate(data):
            x0 = offset
            y0 = canvas_height - (i + 1) * (bar_width + spacing)
            x1 = offset + bar_width
            y1 = canvas_height - i * (bar_width + spacing)
            
            canvas.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill="blue")
            canvas.create_text((x0 + x1) // 2, (y0 + y1) // 2, text=str(height), fill="white")
        
        canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
        self.root.update_idletasks()

    def draw_linked_list(self, data, canvas):
        canvas.delete("all")
        canvas_height = 180
        canvas_width = max(800, len(data) * 100)
        bar_width = canvas_width / (len(data) + 1)
        node_width=60

